# python class method different from non-class function

Tags: python, class, function, methods, scope

I suspect that the action of the class methods on some set of variables is different from the action of the corresponding non-class function. Here is an example. Assume we have a set of variables: A, B, C and we want to modify them over time according to some algorithms. There are 2 possible implementations:

1) with class:

```
   class variables:
       def __init__(self):
           self.A = 0.0
           self.B = 0.0
           self.C = 0.0
       def changeA(self):
           self.A = some function of A, B and C         
       def changeB(self):
           self.B = some function of A, B and C
       def changeC(self):
           self.C = some function of A, B and C
```

And call many times:

```
    ob = variables()
    i = 0 
    while i<N:
        ob.changeA()
        ob.changeB()
        ob.changeC()
        i = i + 1
```

2) without classes

```
    A, B, C = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    def changeA(A,B,C):
        A = some function of A, B and C (same as in class method)
        return A
    def changeB(A,B,C):
        B = some function of A, B and C (same as in class method)
        return B
    def changeC(A,B,C):
        C = some function of A, B and C (same as in class method)
        return C
```

And call many times:

```
    i = 0 
    while i<N:
        A = changeA(A,B,C)
        B = changeB(A,B,C)
        C = changeC(A,B,C)
        i = i + 1
```

In my opinion, the results of 2 approaches must be identical. The only difference is the namespace where the variables A, B and C are known (either local in object or globally for function implementation - but in both cases method have access to required variables). However, the results of two methods seem to be different. So my question is there anything i'm missing in class method implementation/understanding?

To be more specific, an example of implementation of methods changeA:

As a class method:

```
    (... inside the class)
    def changeA(self):
        self.A = self.A + 2.0*self.B - 3.0*self.C*(self.B-self.A)
```

As a function:

```
    def changeA(A,B,C):
        A = A + 2.0*B - 3.0*C*(B-A)
        return A
```

Comment: Did you think about prefixing every use of A, B and C in the class with `self.`? Otherwise you'll access global names instead of local ones.

Comment: What makes you think that these behave differently? Can you post some specific (working) code that shows a difference?

Comment: You haven't defined a class variable in either example. In example (1) you've got an instance with three instance attributes (variables).

Comment: I have added some edits to answer questions of Jonas Wielicki and lvc. To msv: What do you mean by class variable? Isn't A, B and C are the class variables?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that in the 1st case, each time a new `variables` instance is created the values of `A`, `B` and `C` are reset, which is not the case in the 2nd approach where they seem to be global. Depending on how you use these instances, results can be impacted.

**EDIT:** after OP's question in comment, here is how to define class variables:

```
>>> class Variables:
    A = 0.0
    B = 0.0
    C = 0.0

    def changeA(self):
           Variables.A = Variables.A + Variables.B * Variables.C


>>> v = Variables()
>>> v.changeA()
>>> v.A
0.0
>>> Variables.A
0.0
>>>
```

As you can see, no need to define an `__init__` method any longer. And you can access these variables by either `instance.A` or `class.A`.

Comment: How can make class variables A, B and C global withing the class (like in c++)? My objective is to modify some global variables without them being reset at each iteration. This seems to be straightforward in function implementation, but how do I do this in class implementation?